# Match for words that have same letters

Tags: regex

I am trying to match words that have the same letter repeated as the second letter, the ending character and an in the middle 1 times, and I need to capture the second letter and match the whole line.

words examples

```
syzygy
error
banana
```

I tried doing

```
^[a-z]([a-z])[a-z]+[a-z]+\1$
```

and this matches the lines and captures my second letter, but I need to make sure the second letter is repeated

```
 s(y)z y <-same as second character g y <- ends in same character
```

so I need to be sure in a string that y is at the second position, 1 time in the middle, and ending of the string

Comment: Your 1st sentence totally went over my head. Can you post the expected output?

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be right"? Why not try it first and post what you obtained and what you wanted to get?

Comment: @user2852075: How do you define middle here?

Comment: somewhere in the string between the second char and ending char

Comment: so the same character is repeated 3 times in the string, starting from the second position

Comment: `an in the middle 1 times` This requirement was added after 30 minutes after the original post. Why?

Comment: I understood me asking before correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this, if I understand you correctly is using a *negative look ahead*.

```
^.(.)(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?:(?!\1).)*\1$
```

The dot `.` matches any single character, except line break characters. By using `\1`, we reference the match that was saved in the first capture group.

See [regular expression explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E.%28.%29%28?%3a%28?!%5C1%29.%29%2a%5C1%28?%3a%28?!%5C1%29.%29%2a%5C1%24)

See [live demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/tU1vQ0) of capturing the second character and matching the whole string.

See [live demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/jI8iR2) of how `\1` is matching repeated characters.

Comment: This might be a problem if there are more than one \1's in the middle.

Comment: OP said words with `3` repeating chars, starting at second position, one somewhere in the middle and ending?

Comment: I thought he said 3 positions, where `yyyyyyyyyyyy` would pass. But, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

```
 # ^[a-z]([a-z])[a-z]*\1[a-z]*\1$

 ^ 
 [a-z]  
 ( [a-z] )   # (1), Second letter
 [a-z]* 
 \1          # A Backref to second letter in the middle
 [a-z]* 
 \1          # A Backref to second letter at the end
 $
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^.(.).*?\1.*?\1$
```

Comment: this matches more than one repeating char in the middle

Comment: +1 Based on the OP's original problem statement, this is correct.

Comment: @user2852075: It wasn't clear before your edits that you want exactly 3 matches of same char.

Comment: I thought I asked it right before, basically second char is same as the end char and one char of the same in the middle